# Laptop Power Button Won't Shut Down Stuck Installing Windows Updates

Tags: laptop, windows-update, sleep, shutdown, power

I have a Toshiba Tecra R950 laptop with Windows 7 64 bit. Last night it seemed stuck on the installing updates screen while shutting down. I let it run all night and it is still stuck. So I decided to shut it off by holding down the power button. Normally, if I hold it down long enough it will turn off, but now all it does is go to sleep. When I power it back on it wakes up and is stuck on the installing updates screen. I unplugged the power and am waiting for the battery to die. Any other ideas on how I can force it to shut down faster?

Comment: Remove the battery?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull the battery pack out. Flip the computer upside down, and you should see little sliding locks, slide them and it should release the battery. When you do this, make sure the laptop is not plugged in to power, otherwise it will stay on.